# How to simplify $(aX+D)^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Given a scale $a$, a full rank, symmetric, off-diagonal matrix $X$ and diagonal matrix $D$

Can the following inverse be simplified so that the scalar $a$ is not included inside the inverse operator?

$(aX+D)^{-1}$

**UPDATE:**

Actually the inverse of $X$ and $D$ can be obtained, so the question can also be considered as approximating  $(aX+D)^{-1}$ by $a$, $X^{-1}$ and $D^{-1}$

Comment: possible duplicate of [inverse of diagonal plus sum of rank one matrices](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497799/inverse-of-diagonal-plus-sum-of-rank-one-matrices)

Comment: @Deliasaghi Thanks for the reference but I am not looking at rank one matrix

Answer (score 0):

There are some results for some special cases. For instance for low-rank updates, see Woodbury expression [Question 297799](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497799/inverse-of-diagonal-plus-sum-of-rank-one-matrices).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Yet I am not looking at rank one matrix so the answer provided may not be helpful at all.