# Inverse of matrix of a specific form.

Tags: matrices, inverse, matrix-decomposition

I want to compute a matrix of the form

$$(D+AA^{\prime})^{-1} AA^{\prime}  \tag{1}$$

where $D$ is a diagonal matrix and $A$ is a $p \times k$ matrix with $p \gg k$. I got this expression after applying Woodbury matrix identity to another matrix, and it will not help to use it again.

I was wondering if there exists some approximation to the matrix of the above form so that I do not have to calculate the inverse directly. Thanks!

Comment: Since $p\gg k$ wouldn't it be better to work with Woodbury in the form $(I+A'D^{-1}A)^{-1}$ instead? BTW is $D$ positive?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it is. I have some other problem with Woodbury. As p is large, the matrix $(I+A^{\prime}D^{-1}A)^{-1}$ is over-informative, i.e., all the entries are very large, and I can not numerically invert that. That is why, I used Woodbury, and now I need some approximation of given matrix, post-multiplied by a vector.

Comment: Yes, entries of $D$ are all positive.

Comment: One possibility is to write your matrix as $I-(D+AA')^{-1}D=I-(I+D^{-1}A\cdot A')^{-1}$ and try to run [rank-one update](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) $k$ times. Another option is to try [conjugate directions method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method).

Comment: [Related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2004489/inverse-of-i-taa-prime)